# Using Stata's keep command on multiple blocks of variables

Tags: stata

I just started working on a massive dataset with 5 million observations and lots and lots of variables. To process this faster, I want to select only some variables of interest and drop the rest.

with `keep`, I could select a block of variables, very simple:

```
keep varx1-x5
```

However, the variables I want are not in order in the dataset:

```
varx1 varx2 varx3 varz1 varz2 vary1 vary2 vary3
```

Where I don't want the `varz` variables. I want only the blocks with `varx` and `vary`.

So. I'm not very good at loops, but I tried this:

```
foreach varname of varlist varx1-varx3 vary1-vary3  {
keep `varname'
}
```

This doesn't work,  because it `keep`s only `varx1`, then tries to `keep` the others, and errors out because they have just been `drop`ped.

How can I tell `keep` to select multiple blocks of variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know all the variables you want to drop, to keep only the blocks with `varx` and `vary` :

```
keep varx* varz*
```

The `*` means  “match zero or more” of the preceding expression.

Comment: The stated meaning of `*` is not correct in this context. It is fine for regular expressions, but here it just means, e.g., all variables that start with `varx` suffixed with anything else. For example: `varx1`, `varx2`, `varxwhatever`. The quote from `help varlist` is "match one or more characters". (The original poster wishes to `keep` `varx*`and `vary*`, not `varz*`.)

Comment: Of  course. How silly I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `keep` which will wipe out variables not given to the command, try `drop`, which will delete only those you specify. The loop is not necessary. An example:

```
clear 
set obs 0

*----- example vars -----

gen varx1 = .
gen varx2 = .
gen varx3 = .
gen varz1 = .
gen varz2 = .
gen vary1 = .
gen vary2 = .
gen vary3 = .

*----- what you want -----

drop varz*
```

Both commands are documented jointly, so `help keep` or `help drop` would have gotten you there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, using drop with my data is not an option. The example I gave is a very simple version of the massive amounts of variables I have to deal with. So the process of dropping is very timeinefficient. It makes much more sense to select/keep :)

Comment: Have you **any** evidence for this assertion? Whether you ask for the variables you want or those you don't want, the dataset ends up the same. Why do think it matters to Stata?

Comment: Sorry,  never saw your post and now my reasoning from then escapes me. I was a young hot-headed man back then.